# Server stack trace: at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize

Tags: c#, wcf

I have got a WCF service, which is hosted on one server, this service has a class like this,

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable()]
public class FruitObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string fruitName;
    [DataMember]
    public byte[] data;
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IFruits
{
    [OperationContract]
    FruitObject[] GetFruitsFromCrate(string cratePosition, string[] fruitNames);
}
```

Now I am calling it using a proxy on a different server by this,

```
 SomeProject.WebServices.Inside.FruitObject[] fruits = proxy.GetFruitsFromCrate(cratePosition, fruitNames);
```

**Exception**

> Description: Type
>   'System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException' in
>   Assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken="I removed it"' is not marked as serializable.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context,
>   SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter,
>   ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)

Comment: I also tried with [Serializable] but no gain :(

Comment: Hmm, what happens if you change your fields to properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding this to web.config,

```
 1: <configuration>
   2:   <system.serviceModel>
   3:     <bindings>
   4:       <basicHttpBinding>
   5:         <binding name="myBindingForBigArrays"
   6:             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
   7:           <readerQuotas
   8:               maxDepth="64"
   9:               maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
  10:               maxArrayLength="2147483647"
  11:               maxBytesPerRead="4096"
  12:               maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
  13:         </binding>
  14:       </basicHttpBinding>
  15:     </bindings>
```

Problem was with readerQuotas as it was set to default and services were failing on deserializing.